# Laravel generates error while sending lists of posts to users

Tags: laravel, error-handling

RegistrationController.php

```
use App\User;
use App\Post;
use App\Notifications\LatestPosts;
use App\Notifications\WelcomeEmail:
public function store()
{
auth()->login($user);
$allUsers = User::latest()->get();
$posts = Post::latest()->get();
$user->notify(new WelcomeEmail($user));
$allUsers->notify(new LatestPosts($posts));
return redirect(‘/dashboard’);
}
```

WelcomeEmail.php

```
use App\User;
class WelcomeEmail extends Notification
{
use Queueable:
public $user;
public function __construct(User $user)
{
$this->user = $user;
}
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
$user = $this->user;
return (new MailMessage)
->subject(‘Thanks for registering’)
->markdown(‘emails.newusers.welcome’, compact(‘user’));
}
}
```

LatestPosts.php

```
use App\Post;
class LatestPosts extends Notification
{
use Queueable;
public $posts;
public function __construct(Post $posts)
{
$this->posts = $posts;
}
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
$posts = $this->posts;
return (new MailMessage)
->subject(‘Latest posts for you’)
->markdown(‘emails.posts.latestposts’, compact(‘posts’));
}
}
```

New users register successfully, welcome email is sent successfully but it gives me this error for sending latest posts to users.

```
Argument 1 passed to App\Notifications\LatestPosts::__construct() must be an instance of App\Post, instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection given
```

Basically, I want to send a list of posts to all users (I know it’s not efficient to send it while new users register but just want to see how it will work out even if I send it while new users register) Someone please help me out in this. What do I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: See the error, it says that the construct method expects a model instance of `App\Post`, but you're sending a collection in the controller `$allUsers->notify(new LatestPosts($posts));` . So change the type from model instance to collection in the construct function.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Aashish but how do I change from model instance to collection in the construct function? Do I query directly inside the construct function? Please explain how that will be done?

Comment: Try this and let me know.      `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;`        `public function __construct(Collection $posts)
{....`

Comment: This is the error I get .....```Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::notify does not exist```

Comment: I think it's because of this `$allUsers->notify(` , because $allUsers is a collection. If that's the case then just loop over all the users and send them one by one.

Comment: So within the controller here’s the adjustment. 
```@foreach($allUsers as $singleUser)$singleUser->notify(new LatestPosts($posts));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218524/discussion-between-aashish-gaba-and-cd4success).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In registration controller

```
use App\User;
use App\Post;
use App\Notifications\LatestPosts;
use App\Notifications\WelcomeEmail:
public function store()
{
   auth()->login($user);
   $allUsers = User::latest()->get();
   $posts = Post::latest()->get();
   $user->notify(new WelcomeEmail($user));

   foreach($allUsers as $u){
     $u->notify(new LatestPosts($posts));
   }

   return redirect(‘/dashboard’);
}
```

LatestPost

```
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class LatestPosts extends Notification
{
   use Queueable;
   public $posts;

   public function __construct(Collection $posts)
   {
      $this->posts = $posts;
   }

   public function toMail($notifiable)
   {
      $posts = $this->posts;
      return (new MailMessage)
        ->subject(‘Latest posts for you’)
        ->markdown(‘emails.posts.latestposts’, compact(‘posts’));
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the signature of your constructor:

```php
use App\Post;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;

class LatestPosts extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    public $posts;

    public function __construct(Collection $posts) // use `Collection`, not `Post`
    {
        $this->posts = $posts;
    }

    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        $posts = $this->posts;

        return (new MailMessage)
            ->subject('Latest posts for you')
            ->markdown('emails.posts.latestposts', compact('posts'));
    }
}
```